# How to make the text same height as the icon?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

i edit a web part currently and having a problem. You can see the picture at below. I want to put my text at the top just beside my icon. I try move and the text and picture but it cannot work. Can anyone please help me? How to make the text same height as the icon?
[image]

Comment: please paste your html code, based on structure you have used we can apply css....

Comment: This is a CSS question, not a SharePoint question. You need to learn CSS about ``position:relative``